# Calculus of Variations; Maximum enclosed area problem.

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

The problem reads: " You are given a string of fixed length $\ell$ with one end fastened at the origin $O$, and you are to place the string in the
$\left(x, y\right)$ plane with its other end on the x axis in such a way as to maximise the area between the string and the x axis. Show that the required shape is a semicircle ".

Hint: Show that the area can be written as
$$J(y) = \frac{1}{c}\int_{0}^{\ell} y(s)\sqrt{1 + (y'(s))^2}ds$$
where $s$ is the arc-length along the string, and then use the following first integral of the $\mbox{Euler-Lagrange}$ equation
$$
F - y'\,\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = C\quad\mbox{where}\quad
y' = dy/ds\quad\mbox{and}\quad F = y\sqrt{1 + (y')^2}
$$

***My attempt at a solution:***

I know that the rules of this site state that saying I really don't have a clue what to do is not allowed but I genuinely have been stuck on this for all of today and for hours last night as well. I know that if y were a function of x, then the following would work
$$\frac{\triangle{s^2}}{\triangle{x^2}} = 1 + \frac{\triangle{y^2}}{\triangle{x^2}}$$
and then taking the limit as x tends to 0 would give
$$ds = \sqrt{1 + (y')^2}dx$$

But due to the question stating that $y$ is a function of $s$, the arc-length. I have absolutely no clue where to go, I simply can not see how it is shown. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you !.

Comment: $\mathrm{J}\left[y\right]$ doesn't enforce the restriction ( the string length $\ell$ is a constant ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation seems to be wrong

The Area is given by
$$J[y]=\int_0^\ell y dx$$

The length of the differential element: 
$$(ds)^2=(dx)^2+(dy)^2$$
$$dx=\sqrt{1-(y'(s))^2}ds$$
You get
$$J[y]=\int_0^\ell y(s) \sqrt{1-(y'(s))^2}ds$$

Also see [Isoperimetric problem in the calculus of variations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69307/isoperimetric-problem-in-the-calculus-of-variations?rq=1)

Comment: Ahhh, now I see it. Thank you!