# Constants in Euler Lagrange Isoperimetric equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Dido was given a 50 meter hide rope to enclose maximum land area adjoining a sea coast.

$$ \int y ~dx - \lambda \int \sqrt{1+y^{'2}} ~dx;~$$

$$L=y- \lambda \sqrt{1+y^{'2}}  $$

From Euler-Lagrange equation, $x$ does not explicitly occur.

$$  y-\lambda \sqrt{1+y^{'2}} - y'\{ 0-\lambda \frac{y'}{ \sqrt{1+y^{'2}}}\}=h $$

where $h$ is an arbitrary integration constant.

Simplifying, since $\sec \phi= \sqrt{1+y^{'2}},~~$ we arrive at the ode

$$\cos \phi=\dfrac{y-h}{\lambda}$$

There are two constants $(\lambda,h)$.  The Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ of this isoperimetric problem is  recognized geometrically as the semi-circle radius and constant $h$ as a rectangle height onto which the semi-circle is shifted up along the y-axis. The rectangle has sides $(2\lambda,h)$.

Several pairs $(\lambda,h) $ can be chosen with constant perimeter length

$$  \pi \lambda +2 h =50 $$

out of which three options are
[image]

$$ \{\lambda, h\}~=(15.955,10,0), (0, 9.292,25)$$

from which Dido cleverly chooses first  obvious intuitive option $h=0$.

The second and last options are discarded as the object function area itself is compromised.

In this geometry situation a choice of $h=0$  is easy to make.

Should $h$ be always taken zero in such odes ?

An argument that the Lagrangian constant $h$ in the Euler Lagrange equation in *all* such situations should be set be zero seems unacceptable.

In *another isoperimetric problem* seeking solution of maximum area enclosed for give surface area involving such an arbitrary but important constant $c$,

$$ \int \pi r^2 dz - \lambda_1\int 2 \pi r \sqrt{1+r^{'2}} dz$$
which can be also reformed to Lagrangian

$$ r^2-\lambda r  \sqrt{1+r^{'2}}$$

leading to ode using EL equation $$ \cos \phi =\frac{r^2-c^2}{r \lambda} $$

We recognize mean curvature $ H =\dfrac{1}{\lambda} $ for DeLaunay loop surfaces. Constant $c$ is distance between symmetry axis and points of reentrant tangency, the red and yellow lines.

If we set $c=0$ then all these loops reduce to spheres of radius $\lambda.$

[image]

Thanks for all comments applicable in a wider context for choosing/interpreting this arbitrary constant.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69307/11127 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411337/11127 and links therein.

Comment: Your diagrams do not explore the additional possibility that the center of circle lies on the other side of the boundary. These are physically more plausible cases. Perhaps a second-variation argument will allow you to locate the true optimum from this continuum of solutions.